# RCA victor 35x tube radio loop antenna replica?

Tags: antenna-construction, wire-antenna

There is this one youtube video I have not been able to find again, where someone with a similar model radio was making replica of the original loop antenna on the back.

I am wanting to make a replica of this antenna [image]

What would be the best way to remake one of these? What kind of gauge wire should I use? Should I add a ground?
I found the schematics for the radio [Tube Schematic](http://www.nostalgiaair.org/Resources/download.asp?FN=%5CM0014914.pdf)

Comment: Youtube.com has a "History" button on the left of the screen that should list your "Watched" videos. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Litz wire can be used. Compare with solid copper wire, it is more efficient and higher Q factor, due to skin effect.

No ground is needed.

Litz wire is used in modern version which uses ferrite core instead of air core. [image: Modern version]

Try search "loop antenna" and you can find more information, like [Wikipedia on loop ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna)